# Python : define a list of a specific type of object

Tags: python, list

I would like to inherit from a list to produce the `myList` class, that only accepts one specific type of object (say ints).
I am sure decorators can do that elegantly.

Comment: Why not inherit from list and override extend, append, and __init__, only with type checking to raise an error if an object of the wrong type is added?

Comment: Sure. This is my first solution. I was just wondering if there was a more generic solution ; I mean a unique solution for any type of object.

Answer (score 4):

What about using [arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html)?

> This module defines an object type
>   which can compactly represent an array
>   of basic values: characters, integers,
>   floating point numbers. Arrays are
>   sequence types and behave very much
>   like lists, except that the type of
>   objects stored in them is constrained.
>   The type is specified at object
>   creation time by using a type code,
>   which is a single character. The
>   following type codes are defined:

Comment: Mmmmm... Can an array store any type of object (instances of my own classes)?

Comment: Yes, one of the types accepted by arrays are 'object', and since everything in Python are objects... Indeed it is the perfect (and only, afaik) way to create heterogeneous sequences.