# How to specify that a parameter is a list of specific objects in Python docstrings

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

I really like using docstrings in Python to specify type parameters when projects get beyond a certain size.

I'm having trouble finding a standard to use to specify that a parameter is a list of specific objects, e.g. in Haskell types I'd use [String] or [A].

Current standard (recognisable by PyCharm editor):

```
def stringify(listOfObjects):
    """
    :type listOfObjects: list
    """
    return ", ".join(map(str, listOfObjects))
```

What I'd prefer:

**OPTION 1**

```
def stringify(listOfObjects):
    """
    :type listOfObjects: list<Object>  
    """
    return ", ".join(map(str, listOfObjects))
```

**OPTION 2**

```
def stringify(listOfObjects):
    """
    :type listOfObjects: [Object]
    """
    return ", ".join(map(str, listOfObjects))
```

I suppose that wasn't a great example - the more relevant use case would be one where the objects in the list must be of a specific type.

**BETTER EXAMPLE**

```
class Food(Object):
    def __init__(self, calories):
        self.calories = calories

class Apple(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self, 200)

class Person(Object):
    energy = 0
    def eat(foods):
        """
        :type foods: [Food]  # is NOT recognised by editor
        """
        for food in foods:
            energy += food.calories
```

So, other than the fact that I'm getting hungry, this example illustrates that if called with a list of the wrong kind of object, the code would break. Hence the importance of documenting not only that it needs a list, but that it needs a list of Food.

**RELATED QUESTION**
[How can I tell PyCharm what type a parameter is expected to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318814/how-can-i-tell-pycharm-what-type-a-parameter-is-expected-to-be)
Please note that I'm looking for a more specific answer than the one above.

Comment: Did you check the PEPs on the python web site?

Comment: I didn't find one for this, but I may have missed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/python-3-annotations-type-hinting-a-list-of-a-specified-type-pycharm (where I learned about Python 3.5's `typing` module).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In comments section of [PyCharm's manual](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) there's a nice hint from developer:

```
#: :type: dict of (str, C)
#: :type: list of str
```

It works for me pretty well. Now it makes me wonder what's the best way to document parametrized classes in Python :).

Comment: This answer is obsolete now, with the creation of [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in late 2014.  But it was a good answer at the time!  :-)

Comment: Note: The answer is only obsolete for Python 3.5 and on.

Answer (score 22):

As pointed out in the [PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-syntax-for-docstrings.html), *a* (legacy, pre-[PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) way of doing this is using square brackets:

> list[Foo]: List of Foo elements
>
> dict[Foo, Bar]: Dict from Foo to Bar

`list of str`, as suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524180/942774),  *does not work* as expected in PyCharm.

Starting with Python 3.5 and the implementation of [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), you can also use type hints, which may be nicely supported by your IDE/editor. How this is easily done in PyCharm is explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html).

In essence, to declare a list return type using type-hinting (Python >=3.5), you may do something like this:

```
from typing import List

"""
Great foo function.

:rtype: list[str]
"""
def foo() -> List[str]:
    return ['some string', 'some other string']
```

Here we declare (somewhat redundantly) that the function `foo` returns a list of strings, both in the type hint `-> List[str]` and in the docstring `:rtype: list[str]`.

Other pre-declared types and more info can be found in the Python docs for [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 4):

in python

```
type([1,2,3]) == type(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

you can also add a string to list of ints.

So for what you are trying to achieve PyCharm would have to magically check your whole code for what you are adding to the list before passing it as argument.

You can take a look at this question [Python : define a list of a specific type of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391995/python-define-a-list-of-a-specific-type-of-object)

Array module however allows only 'basic values'.

Only solution i can think of here is to create your own class that extends python list "FoodsList" that can check for type before adding element.

```
class Food():
    def __init__(self, calories):
        self.calories = calories

class FoodsList(list):
    #you can optionally extend append method here to validate type
    pass

def eat(foods):
    """
    :type foods: FoodsList
    """
    energy = 0
    for food in foods:
        energy += food.calories
    return energy


list = FoodsList()
list.append(Food(3))
list.append(Food(4))
print eat(list)
```

Comment: +1: It solves the problem in a much better way than I was hoping for :) good insight

Comment: though I do suspect that PyCharm is quite capable of 'magically' checking all my code to see what I'm adding to the list - that's kind of what it's designed to do :)

Answer (score 2):

When writing docstrings in the google style you can do:

```
class ToDocument(object):
    """This is my Documentation.

    Args:
        typed_list (:obj:`list` of :obj:`str`): Description of typed list

    """
    ...
```

This also works pretty fine in sphinx, when combined with the napoleon-extension. Refer to the [extension's doc](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html) for more examples on documentation.