# How to properly function annotate / type hint a list of strings

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to properly function annotate or type hint a list of strings. For example, if I had a function like this:

```
def send_email(self, from_address: str, to_addresses: list[str]):
    pass
```

`to_addresses` should be a list of strings.  But when I try to use that annotation I get the following error in my Python 3.4.3 interpreter:

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

I am positive the `list[str]` is causing the issue, because if I change it to `str` the error goes away, but that doesn't properly reflect my intentions for the parameter.

Comment: a list of strings? what if its a list of unicode objects, or a class derived from string?

Comment: I want to hint a list of the primitive str type.  If it's one of those, I won't be able to handle it.

Comment: it can't be checked, unfortunately. what you are asking is essentially looping over all objects in the list and verify them to be `str`. it's just too much work. python is duck-typed, so you shouldn't rely on the actual type of objects in general. yes, i admit it's some-what ridiculous but if you don't like it, you should use some language with type system.

Comment: I'm not asking for it to be checked, I'm just really asking for it to be properly hinted.  I understand that in 3.4 there is no static types or type checking... I just want to properly annotate it.

Comment: write in the docstring then.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of having the annotations?  The annotations exist, I want to use them.

Comment: I found this when looking for a way to type-hint for iterables of strings as well as strings. I ended up using this: `def f(s: Union[Iterable[str], str])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting a list of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-list-of-a-specified-type)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Python 3.4 doesn't specify a format for its function annotations, it merely provides a mechanism that allows you to use any expression as the annotation. How the annotations are interpreted is up to you and the libraries you use.

Python 3.5 standardizes the way function annotations are used for type hinting, as documented in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). To annotate a list of strings, you use `List[str]`, where `List` is imported from the `typing` module. You can also use `Sequence[str]` if your function accepts any list-like sequence, or `Iterable[str]` for any iterable.

Starting with Python 3.9, you can use `list[str]` as a type annotation, which doesn't require importing anything, as documented in [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/).

Answer (score 23):

In Python 3.9+, `list` (with a lowercase `l`) can be used in type annotations and your code should work as is. On older versions of Python you need to import [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) and use it instead

```
from typing import List

to_addresses: List[str]
```

Note the capital `L`.

You might want to consider something more specific, e.g.

```
import typing
Address = typing.NewType("Address")
```

See [NewType docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype)

> The static type checker will treat the new type as if it were a subclass of the original type

Comment: "Why is from_address a str, but to_addresses is a list[str]?" because you can [send an email to multiple addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_copy#Email) but you can't put more than one email in the "From:" field.

Answer (score 12):

This syntax is now valid in [Python 3.9+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections):

> In type annotations you can now use built-in collection types such as `list` and `dict` as generic types instead of importing the corresponding capitalized types (e.g. `List` or `Dict`) from `typing`.

Prior to 3.9 though, you need to use the imported `List` or [in Python 3.7+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7) you can add

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

at the top of your file, which allows using `list[int]` (for example). Note though, [this import only affects *annotations*](https://bugs.python.org/issue45117):

> `from __future__ import annotations` only affects annotations -- just the things after the colon. It makes it so that annotations are never evaluated

It still doesn't allow `list[int]` in arbitrary contexts.

Comment: In Python 3.8, you can enable this behavior with `from __future__ import annotations`. Otherwise you're stuck using `typing.List`.

Comment: @BallpointBen No it doesn't work for `3.8.5`, after this import `Vector = list[float]` still gets "'type' object is not subscriptable" error.

Comment: @asuka you can only use that syntax as a type annotation, not as a value.

Comment: @BallpointBen Thank you! I misunderstood, now it works perfectly.