# How to specify method return type list of (what) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-type

Let's say I have a method like the following

```
def validate(self, item:dict, attrs:dict)-> list:
```

If I want to be more specific and tell that my return type is a list of ValidationMessages?

How should I / Can I achieve that?

(I would check off the mark as a duplicate, since this is not about extending a list or flattening) I'm asking about how to be more specific on identifying the return type of a method...

Comment: Almost-dupe: [Python 3 Annotations: Type hinting a list of a specified type (PyCharm)](//stackoverflow.com/q/24853923)

Comment: Go straigth to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html - define an alias and return that as type hint - your exactuse case would be [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases)

Comment: More an opinion than an answer, but if you want strict type checking, Java is a better choice than Python... Anyway, PatrickArtner's comment is the answer...

Comment: This has nothing to do with flattening a list... @GabrielM

Comment: Yes Patrick's comment is the answer

Comment: Duplicate: [Type hinting a list of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-list-of-a-specified-type)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

With Python 3.6, the built-in [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) package will do the job.

```
from typing import List

def validate(self, item:dict, attrs:dict)-> List[str]:
    ...
```

The notation is a bit weird, since it uses brackets but works out pretty well.

**Edit**: With the new 3.9 version of Python, you can annotate types without importing from the `typing` module. The only difference is that you use real type names instead of defined types in the `typing` module.

```
def validate(self, item:dict, attrs:dict)-> list[str]:
    ...
```

***NOTE***: Type hints are just hints that help IDE. Those types are not enforced. You can add a hint for a variable as `str` and set an `int` to it like this:

```py
a:str = 'variable hinted as str'
a = 5  # See, we can set an int
```

Your IDE will warn you but you will still be able to run the code. Because those are just hints. Python is not a type strict language. Instead, it employs dynamic typing.

Comment: I'm getting a deprecation warning for this now:

    DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated "List"

Comment: @JulianH you should ask this in another question

Comment: is there a way to specify the length of a list that should be returned?

Comment: @lxg95 you can create your own subtype for that which you should ask in seperate question.

Comment: the `typing` package in 2.93 also works. i mean at least it doesn't error out.