# Do python parameter type hints support nested type information?

Tags: python, types

I have a function that is logically as follows:

```
 def computeProbability(
     x_i: np.array(np.int32), 
     colProbabilities: list(dict(string,np.float32))
 ) -> list(double):
     return []  # placeholder
```

My guess is that the most stringent type checking that can be achieved here would be:

```
def computeProbability(x_i: np.array, colProbabilities: list) -> list:
     return []  # placeholder
```

Is that assumption correct?

Comment: You can achieve it to some extent using the `typing` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html ;

Comment: The downvote is one of the less comprehensible ones i've seen.  Whoever did so might  ask themselves "how much python code that I look at actually uses these nested type hints".  I had _never_ seen it i the wild.  I am _anyways_ showing this to co-workers and other classmates because of its usefulness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting a collection of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it ***is*** possible to give *deep* type information.  Just discovered `type hints` from python 3.5+.  These are great for IDE's: e.g. you can do this

```
ListOfDict = List[Dict[str, float]]
```

then  declare a  method that returns a list of Dicts  with string key and float value

```
from typing import List, Dict
Vector = List[float]
ListOfDict = List[Dict[str, float]]
```

Using this:

```
def computeLikelihood(x_i_vals: Vector, allProbs: ListOfDict):
```

Now we can get method hints in the IDE!

[image]

This is a big win for developing nested data structures!