# Enforcing type bounds in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-typing

I am trying to do type enforcement in `Python 3.8` but unable to enforce type bounds. Let's consider the following example:

```
class Animal(object): pass
class Cat(Animal): pass
class Dog(Animal): pass

# now want a list of only cats
list_of_cats:Cat = list()

list_of_cats.append(Cat())
list_of_cats.append(Dog()) # this should not be allowed

for animal in list_of_cats:
  print(type(animal))

---- OUTPUT -----
<class '__main__.Cat'>
<class '__main__.Dog'>
```

Is there a way to enforce type bounds, using language features, in Python `3.8` (like Scala)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Do you want this code to be rejected by a type checker such as MyPy, or do you want an error to be thrown at runtime? Note that the annotation ``list_of_cats:Cat = list()`` is nonsensical, since ``list`` is not compatible with ``Cat``. Did you mean ``list_of_cats: List[Cat] = list()``?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting a collection of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do, but for the simple examples like this,
you can create a custom class that does validation for the method.

```py
class Animal(object): pass

class Cat(Animal): pass

class Dog(Animal): pass

class CatList(list):
    def append(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Cat):
            super().append(item)
        else:
            print(f'Only cats are allowed, {item} not appended')

# now want a list of only cats, use CatList class
list_of_cats: Cat = CatList()

list_of_cats.append(Cat())
list_of_cats.append(Dog())  # this should not be allowed

for animal in list_of_cats:
    print(type(animal))
```

```py
Only cats are allowed, <__main__.Dog object at 0x0000016CF590A4C0> not appended
<class '__main__.Cat'>
```

Note that this is just an example that validates the `append` method only.

Comment: I can do that, but is there something in the language itself? Why isn't it enforcing type?

Comment: There are some module you can use to type check, but the language itself doesn't have that functionality. Check out [this guide](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/).

Comment: it would be best to throw a error instead of a simple print

Comment: @vivax certainly