# 'type' object is not subscriptable at function definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, types, type-hinting

I've defined a function like this

```
def map_json_to_item_dictionary(json: dict[str, dict]) -> dict[int, Any]:
    result: dict[int, Any] = {}

    return result
```

but have an exception `'type' object is not subscriptable at function definition`

PyCharm also prompt an exception `Class 'type' does not define '__getitem__', so the` [] `operator cannot be used on its instances`

Look like python try to access something from `dict`.

What I made wrong?

Comment: [Type hinting a collection of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to import `Dict` and `Any` from the `typing` module:

```
from typing import Dict, Any

def map_json_to_item_dictionary(json: Dict[str, dict]) -> Dict[int, Any]:
    result: Dict[int, Any] = {}

    return result
```