# How to specify type hints for dictionary key and values of a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-typing

I have a dictionary like so:

```
d = { 'my_label': ClassInstance() }
```

I would like to specify type hints to indicate that keys are strings, and values are instances of `ClassInstance`.

Is this possible in Python 3.8?

I found `TypedDict` but that seems to attempt to indicate a fixed set of keys. I would to allow any string as key.

Comment: The code as shown will already infer ``d`` as desired. What else do you need?

Comment: While a tricky question, why would you (practically) want to specify type hints?. Another way could be to serialize your class instance into a JSON string and convert it back when you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting a collection of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Comment: Well, I'm learning more about Python and don't know the answer to this question, so... may not be practical, but doesn't matter, right? 

I would appreciate if people down voting could give some info on what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in Python 3.8

First import dictionary type hint:

```
from typing import Dict
```

and add type hint as following:

```
d: Dict[str, ClassInstance] = { 'my_label': ClassInstance() }
```

In Python 3.9, it is possible to do this without importing Dict from typing ([link to 3.9 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections)) as:

```
d: dict[str, ClassInstance] = { 'my_label': ClassInstance() }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Dict[K, V]`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Dict):

```
from typing import Dict

d: Dict[str, ClassInstance] = { 'my_label': ClassInstance() }
```