# How to type hint a tuple variable in python?

Tags: python, pylance

In python I have a an object `data` that maybe any object it will be.
In vscode `v1, v2 = data # type: str, str` sentence I want `v1, v2`  will popup str method.
In vscode `v1, v2 = data # type: dict, set` sentence I want `v1, v2`  will popup dict, set method.

```py
data = (object, object)

v1, v2 = data # type: str, str

v11, v22= data # type: dict, set
```

But it show error in pylance

```
Type annotation not supported for this type of expression
Unexpected token at end of expression
```

Comment: Interestingly, seems to be working in PyCharm.

Comment: I might be missing something about the question. You type hint a tuple type with the tuple type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting a collection of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, They talk about single varialbe, but my question is to add  type hint for multi variable in once time.

Comment: In that case, it looks like Pylance is just broken. What you have there is correct as per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Pylance is not a very good extension in vscode.

Comment: Starting with 3.9, built-in type `tuple` supports typing, so `tuple[object, object]` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understood your point correctly, but you could declare data type and then variables types if needed:

```
import typing as ty

data = ({}, 0.0)  # type: ty.Tuple[dict, float]

v1: "dict"
v2: "str"
v1, v2 = data
```

I cannot test it on vscode, but the above gives consistent type checking with pyright (which is used by pylance)

EDIT: integrating @Abhijit comment, for python 3.9+ would be:

```
data: tuple[dict, float] = ({}, 0.0)

v1: "dict"
v2: "str"
v1, v2 = data
```

Comment: if my `data = [int, str, set, dict, byte, objectA, objectB, .... objectN]`, this method is not good, it only useful for short container variable.

Comment: Isn't a limit of type hinting itself? If you have n variable that you want to hint you would always end up hinting n variable. Or am I missing something? Also, declaring v1 and/or v2 is optional; you could do it only for the variables you want to be checked. In any case, the above provides syntax to declare tuples as you asked; see also other comments and check docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for example. The n variables hinting problem is a different question and its not fair to extra complexity after the question was answered...

Comment: yes, It's problem of Pylance. your answer is right in my question.