# How to indicate that an argument is a list of lists

Tags: python, arguments

In order to indicate that an argument is a list one can use:

```py
def fun(words:list):
    code...
```

How can I indicate that an argument should be a list of lists? All I can think about is doing something like this:

```py
def fun(words:(list,list)):
    code...
```

Would that be understandable?

Comment: list[list[str]] ?  [type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `typing` module:

```
from typing import List

def fun(l: List[list]):
    code...
```