# TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
from collecionts.abc import Sequence
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
def first(a: Sequence[T]) -> T:
    return a[0]
```

In my understanding, I can pass any Sequence-like object as parameter into `first` function, like:

```
first([1,2,3])
```

and it returns `1`

However, it raises a TypeError:' ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable. What is going on here? How can I make it work that I have a function using `typing` module which can take first element whatever its type?

UPDATE

If I use `from typing import Sequence`,it runs alright,what is the difference between `from collections.abc import Sequence` and `from typing import Sequence`

Comment: Actually that produces a ModuleNotFoundError... Fixing that, you only see a TypeError if you're using Python <3.9, in which case you need the typing version not the abc version: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting a collection of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Comment: TLDR: If you are using a Python version before 3.9 you must use the corresponding generic from ``typing``.

Comment: https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/5916

Answer (score 2):

two things.

The first one is that the typing module will not raise errors at runtime if you pass arguments that do not respect the type you indicated. Typing module helps for general clarity and for intellisense or stuff like that.

Regarding the error that you encounter is probably beacuse of the python version you are using. Try to upgrade to python >= 3.9

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a difference from Python 3.8 and 3.9.

In this thread: https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/5916
people suggest doing some future imports.

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
    class Test(UserDict[str, int]):
        """Class."""
else:
    class Test(UserDict):
        """Class."""
```