# Python Typing - Specify type for specific index in list

Tags: python, typing

i need to set a specific type for an index in a list (or specify each type individually)

for example:

```py
from typing import List

my_list: List[int, str, int] = [1, 'a', 2] # is something like this possible?
```

i know `typing.TypedDict` can specify the type for each key, but is there something like this for a list?

Comment: `list` is the wrong data structure here as the number of elements is generally not fixed in lists. You can do that using a `tuple`, i.e. `my_tuple: tuple[int, str, int]`.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `list` is the wrong data structure here as the number of elements is generally not fixed in lists. You can do that using a `tuple`, i.e. `my_tuple: tuple[int, str, int]`.

*<sub>-- [comment](/q/71316219/#comment126058889_71316219) by 
[Selcuk](/users/2011147/selcuk)</sub>*